# Contenteditable is not working in iOS safari

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari, contenteditable

In ios `contenteditable = true` and `-webkit-user-select: text` but content editable is not working. when I put a code

```
$('.contentdiv).on("touchstart", function() {
$(this).focus();
});
```

then I am able to edit it. But the next problem is I am unable to move cursor. The cursor is always on the left side.

Suppose my Initial text is: `ayush`
then my cursor is before the `'a'` 
now I wrote something then , `somethingayush` 
and again click it then my cursor is before `'s'` and I am unable to move the cursor.

Any answer should be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had to change it into textarea at that time as it was urgent